# Where in Linq using ObjectParameter

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I want to use ObjectParameter inside a LINQ query in the following way:

```
var query = systemEntities.Clients.Where("it.age > @a", new ObjectParameter("a", 20));
```

Then, I want to add another N where clauses to the same query like this:

```
var query = query.Where("it.age < @b", new ObjectParameter("b", 20));
```

Can i use the same ObjectParameter's name multiple times like this?

```
var query = systemEntities.Clients.Where("it.age > @a", new ObjectParameter("a", 20));

var query = query.Where("it.age < @a", new ObjectParameter("a", 20));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896238.aspx

> Parameters must be unique in the
>   ObjectParameterCollection. There
>   cannot be two parameters in the
>   collection with the same name.